# How can I switch firebase configuration using toggle in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I am using reactnative, redux and firebase.
Now i want to config two diff firebase env one is development and other one is production.

I implemented a toggle to switch the firebase diff account.

i put firebase config file in **./App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';

import store from './src/config/store';
import AppNavigation from './src/navigation';

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyAandJABqieT3fXk2palvAgbYz5B8y9EsM',
      authDomain: 'practiciaappsubu.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://practiciaappsubu.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'practiciaappsubu',
      storageBucket: 'practiciaappsubu.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: '753143230840'
    });
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
    console.log('logged In');
      } else {
    console.log('not looged in');
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
    <AppNavigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The toggle is there is Home component. So, after change the toggle from Home componet, how can i get the toggle status in ./App.js file?

The **Home.js** (component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Switch
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

import { Button, Section } from './helpers';
import { userType } from '../config/MasterData';
import { firebaseEnvAction } from '../actions/HomeAction';

class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: '.: Practicia :.'
  };

onPressSignupAs(userInfo) {
  // Navigate to sign up page with the user information
  console.log(userInfo);
}

onPressLogin() {
  // Navigate to login page
  const navigateToLogin = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'login',
    params: {}
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateToLogin);
}

firebaseEnv(val) {
  this.props.firebaseEnvAction(val);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image
        style={styles.logo}
        source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')}
          />
        </View>
      <View style={styles.contentArea}>
        <Text style={styles.signInAs}>Sign Up As...</Text>
        <Section>
          <Button
          onPress={this.onPressSignupAs.bind(this, userType.teacher)}
          >
        {userType.teacher.showText}
          </Button>
        </Section>
        <Section>
          <Button
          onPress={this.onPressSignupAs.bind(this, userType.parent)}
          >{userType.parent.showText}</Button>
        </Section>
        <Section>
          <Button
          onPress={this.onPressSignupAs.bind(this, userType.student)}
          >
          {userType.student.showText}
          </Button>
        </Section>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.LoginBox}>
        <Text style={styles.LoginText}>Already have an account? </Text>
        <Section>
          <Button
          style={styles.buttonLogin}
          styleText={styles.buttonText}
          onPress={this.onPressLogin.bind(this)}
          >
        Login
          </Button>
        </Section>
        <Section>
          <Text style={styles.firebaseText}>Firebase:
        <Switch
          value={this.props.HomeReducer.firebaseToggle}
          onValueChange={(val) => this.firebaseEnv(val)}
          disabled={false}
          activeText={'Prod'}
          inActiveText={'Dev'}
          circleSize={30}
          barHeight={1}
          circleBorderWidth={3}
          backgroundActive={'green'}
          backgroundInactive={'gray'}
          circleActiveColor={'#30a566'}
          circleInActiveColor={'#000000'}
        />
          </Text>
        </Section>
      </View>
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  firebaseText: {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#9DDAEE',
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  userType: {
    fontSize: 23,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: '#3BAFDA',
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
  },
  contentArea: {
    marginLeft: 40,
    marginRight: 40,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  logoContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  logo: {
    width: 250,
    height: 75,
  },
  signInAs: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  LoginBox: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 40,
    marginRight: 40,
  },
  LoginText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  buttonLogin: {
    backgroundColor: '#C4C4C4',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#000000',
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  firebaseEnvAction
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to dispatch an action when the switch is toggled that tears down your firebase instance (`firebase.initializeApp({...});`) and initializes a new firebase app with the credentials you want. This means you'll probably want to dispatch a new `initilizeFirebase` action in your `App.js` `componentWillMount` function. Then your `Home.js` should pull the configured firebase instance from the store. This also means you'll probably want to keep your firebase instance in the store as well.

Comment: I think you want to say that 
in App.js -> componentWillMount   
need to dispatch an action "initilizeFirebase"
and in action "initilizeFirebase" will have the firebase initialized.

So, when toggle on from "Home.js" will dispatch action "initilizeFirebase" to configure production firebase config.

Am i right? or you want to say something different?

Comment: I think we are saying similar things. Basically initialize the firebase when the app starts (app.js#cdm) and allow the button to dispatch the same action but with a different action argument.